# How do I combine two columns and then do a quasi fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, concat-ws

### MySQL

**Table: cities**

```
+----+----------+
| id |   city   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | New York |
+----+----------+
```

**Table: stations**

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| id |     name     | city_id |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  |   Woodlawn   |    1    |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 2  | Mosholu Pkwy |    1    |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

### PHP

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string('woodlawn new york');

$a = mysql_query("

    SELECT s.id FROM cities AS c, stations AS s 

    WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', s.name, c.city) LIKE '%$string%' AND c.id = s.city_id

");

while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
   echo $b['id'];
}
```

### Problem

The example above works fine, however, when I try to search for:

```
 $string = mysql_real_escape_string('mosholu new york');
```

I get 0 results, unless I explicitly search for **mosholu pkwy new york**.

### Possible Options?

Obviously I cannot use `FULLTEXT` search in combination with `CONCAT_WS`. And I would also really like to keep the structure of the tables as they are, having one table for the `cities` and one for the `stations`.

So, is the only option to add a fourth column to the `stations` table that includes **the station name and city name** and then do a `FULLTEXT` search on that?

But it would just be a pain in the butt, if for example I had to update the city name and then change it for all the rows in the `stations` table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace whitespace in `$string` with `%` wildcards—you can do this in either PHP or MySQL as you prefer; for example, in MySQL:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM   cities AS c JOIN stations AS s ON c.id = s.city_id
WHERE  CONCAT_WS(' ', s.name, c.city) LIKE REPLACE('%$string%', ' ', '%')
```